# Cant scaffold API controler in razor pages application

Tags: c#, api, scaffolding, razor-pages

I am trying to scaffold API controler with Entity Framework and during the process ther is some error. Any idea what is wrong?

Console output shows information as follow:

```
Running the generator 'controller'...
Attempting to figure out the EntityFramework metadata for the model and DbContext: 'Product'
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
      Entity Framework Core 3.0.0-preview4.19216.3 initialized 'ProductsDbContext' using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer' with options: MaxPoolSize=128 
Method not found: 'System.Type Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.IProperty.get_ClrType()'.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.ActionInvoker.<BuildCommandLine>b__6_0()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.ActionInvoker.Execute(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.CodeGenCommand.Execute(String[] args)
```

Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: what is the relation between razor pages and Entity Framework? can you share your code as well. just a side note; there is api and mvc two different things, razor views is more related to mvc.

Comment: You are using a Preview version. That looks like a bug in it.